# How to get Point feature from Mouse interaction in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I am unable to get point features from event coordinate like below

```
 $(map.getViewport()).on('click', function (evt) {
            //var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
            var coordinate = map.getEventCoordinate(evt.originalEvent);
layer.getSource().getFeaturesAtCoordinate(coordinate);
}
```

It's returning empty array. But if I use `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,function)` its working but it is not dependable. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "forEachFeatureAtPixel ... is not dependable"?

Comment: Sometimes it returns wrong result if some of your css changes, mainly in terms of pixel.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Can you open a ticket on [GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3) with an example showing this problem? Thanks.